# C#", EF: Fluent-Ignore Interface methods on certain classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datamodel

So I have my models, one of which is called BaseBird.  BaseBird is a model that is contained in my other models; Turkey, Chicken, Ostrich. Because of this, I created an interface called IBaseBird, and I delegated it to the BaseBird property.

```
    public class Turkey: IBaseBird 
    {
       public virtual BaseBird BaseBird { get; set; }

    public string BeakType
    {
        get { return BaseBird.BeakType; }
        set { BaseBird.BeakType = value; }
    }
```

Unfortunately, this has the side effect of when I create my migrations and such, it creates all the BaseBird columns on the model.  I've seen and tried to implement various ways to Ignore columns such as

```
   foreach (var property in typeof (IBaseBird).GetProperties())
   {
      modelBuilder.Types().Configure(m =>  m.Ignore(); );
```

But this ignores the columns for my entire data model , including my BaseBird model.

Then I've tried to shoehorn this into the modelBuilder, but I can't seem to find a way to dynamically reference a property by only having it's name.

```
        foreach (var property in typeof (IBaseBird).GetProperties())
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Turkey>().Ignore(t => t.property.Name);
        }
```

But this just throws errors since I haven't been able to figure out how to access properties dynamically.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have found a comparable solution.  The solution is to create an abstract class called BaseBird which is a simple copy of a class called SimpleBird.  I then put all the methods I want my subclasses to have on an interface called IBaseBird which BaseBird implements of course.

The next step is then to make sure you subclasses extend BaseBird.  Now, annotate all the properties of BaseBird with [Ignore].

By doing this, I can keep my delegated behavior, while still using an interface throughout my domain.